# List of dictionaires in series mapped to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
data = {'name': {0: 'mypath\\is\this', 1: 'mynewpath\\is\this'},
        'vals': {0: [{'name1': 'val1'}, {'name2': 'val2'}, {'name3': 'val3'}],
                 1: [{'name1': 'val1'}, {'name2': 'val2'}, {'name3': 'val3'}]}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

name                       vals
mypath\is\this             [{name1:val1},{name2:val2},{name3:val3}]
mynewpath\is\this          [{name1:val1},{name2:val2},{name3:val3}]
```

How can i expand the values column and map the key to the create a new name keeping the value associated to it appropriately.

Expected output like below:

```
name                    vals
mypath\is\this\name1    val1
mypath\is\this\name2    val2
mypath\is\this\name3    val3
mynewpath\is\this\name1 val1
mynewpath\is\this\name2 val2
mynewpath\is\this\name3 val3
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with minimal example first :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   "name": ["mypath\is\this", "mynewpath\is\this"],
    "vals":[[{"name1":"val1"},{"name2":"val2"},{"name3":"val3"}], [{"name1":"val1"},{"name2":"val2"},{"name3":"val3"}]]
})
```

The solution consists in split the list of dict in **each** row into a DataFrame with the piece of code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "name":
        row["name"],
        "key": [element for d in row["vals"] for element in list(d.keys())],
        "value":
        [element for d in row["vals"] for element in list(d.values())]
    })
```

Then juste `concatenate` it and manipulate string to get the desired output.

Here the complete code :

```
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({
        "name":
        row["name"],
        "key": [element for d in row["vals"] for element in list(d.keys())],
        "value":
        [element for d in row["vals"] for element in list(d.values())]
    }) for index, row in df.iterrows()
])
df["name"] = df["name"] + "\\" + df["key"]
df = df.drop("key", axis=1)
```

Note 1 : I put `\\` because `\` is an espace character.

Note 2 : I use list comprehension to iterate over the rows of the dataframe, this is much easier to concatenate all the dataframe after.

Answer (score 1):

I really tried for a bit to get a vectorized solution. But the `df.vals` being a Series of list of dicts instead of just a Series of dicts threw me off. Hopefully we see some others chime in with better solutions.

At the very list, here's what I've managed to come by. You may find it useful. Please note that this is not taking advantage of vectorization since I'm using apply on the row axis.

```
>>> df
                name                                               vals
0     mypath\is\this  [{'name1': 'val1'}, {'name2': 'val2'}, {'name3...
1  mynewpath\is\this  [{'name1': 'val1'}, {'name2': 'val2'}, {'name3...
>>> def explode_column(row):
...     for column in row.vals:
...             for key,value in column.items():
...                     row[key] = value
...     return row
...
>>> exploded_df = df.apply(explode_column, axis=1)
>>> exploded_df
                name                                               vals name1 name2 name3
0     mypath\is\this  [{'name1': 'val1'}, {'name2': 'val2'}, {'name3... val1  val2  val3
1  mynewpath\is\this  [{'name1': 'val1'}, {'name2': 'val2'}, {'name3... val1  val2  val3
>>> melted_df = exploded_df.melt(id_vars=['name'], value_vars=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])
>>> melted_df
                name variable value
0     mypath\is\this    name1  val1
1  mynewpath\is\this    name1  val1
2     mypath\is\this    name2  val2
3  mynewpath\is\this    name2  val2
4     mypath\is\this    name3  val3
5  mynewpath\is\this    name3  val3
>>> melted_df['new_name'] = melted_df.name.str.cat(melted_df.variable, sep="\\")
>>> melted_df
                name variable value                 new_name
0     mypath\is\this    name1  val1     mypath\is\this\name1
1  mynewpath\is\this    name1  val1  mynewpath\is\this\name1
2     mypath\is\this    name2  val2     mypath\is\this\name2
3  mynewpath\is\this    name2  val2  mynewpath\is\this\name2
4     mypath\is\this    name3  val3     mypath\is\this\name3
5  mynewpath\is\this    name3  val3  mynewpath\is\this\name3
```

Answer (score 1):

Because we have Python objects as values, a vectorized solution seems not feasible. Using a list comprehension makes sense:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('\\'.join((r[1]['name'], list(x.keys())[0])), list(x.values())[0]) 
                  for r in df.iterrows() for x in r[1]['vals']], columns=['name', 'vals'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      name  vals
0     mypath\is\this\name1  val1
1     mypath\is\this\name2  val2
2     mypath\is\this\name3  val3
3  mynewpath\is\this\name1  val1
4  mynewpath\is\this\name2  val2
5  mynewpath\is\this\name3  val3
```